# Sliding a div using jQuery scrollleft

Tags: jquery, html, button, scroll, click

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so this is probably a noobish question.  I want to move a div left and right, manually (not animated).  Specifically, I want to be able to click a Left button, and it moves left 100px, or click a Right button, and it moves right 100px.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious (probably multiple obvious things), but I've done a lot of checking, and I haven't been able to find anything that helps.  I am using the basically self-contained code below as a test.  The div just doesn't move.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#left").click( function() {
          var pos = $("#cont").scrollLeft()-100;
          $("#cont").scrollLeft(pos);
        });
        $("#right").click( function() {
          var pos = $("#cont").scrollLeft()+100;
          $("#cont").scrollLeft(pos);
        });
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="cont" style="position:relative; overflow:auto; width:400px; height:50px; border:10px solid #D6D6D6;"></div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="left" value="Left">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="right" value="Right">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it seems you are looking for `animate` function http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You can use marginLeft. Is this what you are looking ? http://jsfiddle.net/8F9ay/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree about the use of Animate.  Here's a link to a fiddle that I created starting with your code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t5R5H/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#left").click(function () {
        $("#cont").animate({
            left: '-=50'
        }, 'slow');
    });
    $("#right").click(function () {
        $('#cont').animate({
            left: '+=50'
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks great, and I appreciate this too...  But see my comment to the answer above. I really need it to instantly pop. Hopefully still using scrollLeft.  If that's impossible, I will probably use your suggestion here.  But I hope the instant pop with scrollLeft is actually possible.

Comment: Instant pop?  You can do that.  Where I specified `'slow'` and @ankitsrist specified `1000`, simply change that value to `1`...As in one millisecond -- then it should pop. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5R5H/5/)

Comment: @DavidTansey how can I stop the the image/div from moving outside the left and right window? At present if you keep pressing 'left' and 'right' button the image/div goes out of the window. I hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take the help of animate function, like this

```
 $('#cont').animate({left:'+100px'}, 1000);
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but when I said "not animated" I really meant that. I know this will seem strange, but for the application I am trying to solve, I really want the div to instantly pop the 100px, not smoothly move the 100px. And I really need to see if I can do it with scrollLeft.

Comment: the 1000 in the end is time in ms

Comment: so you can replace it with zero. Same for scrollLeft.